# ¿Cómo extraer datos de modelo en MongoDB usando cualquier metodo?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

Aqui tenemos la base de datos que estoy utilizando el **GUILDID, TICKETID, CHANNELID, CLOSED,LOCKET,TYPE,CLAIMED,CLAIMEDBY,OPEN** no lo tomaremos en cuenta ya que eso se asigna automaticamente dentro del bot de discord

```
const { model, Schema} = require("mongoose")

let ticketSchema = new Schema({
    GuildID : String,
    MembersID: [String],
    TicketID: String,
    ChannelID: String,
    Closed: Boolean,
    Locked: Boolean,
    Type: String,
    Claimed: Boolean,
    ClaimedBy: String,
    Open:Boolean
})

module.exports = model("Ticket", ticketSchema);
```

Entonces aqui abajo tenemos un ejemplo de cuando un usuario es registrado

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"63d8080ffbe4f5403967c0ae"}
,"GuildID":"1066373193767592047",
"MembersID["811664013313310720"],
"TicketID":"2",
"ChannelID":"1069680997962092684",
"Closed":false,
"Locked":false,
"Type":"Hola",
"Claimed":false,
"Open":false,
"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

La String del member id es un identificador unico de cada usuario de discord entonces la necesito para poder verificar en la base de datos si hay un usuario con la ID y si tiene un ticket abierto en este caso seria

**EJ**
MembersID: [String] == MembersID: [String] && Open:Boolean
811664013313310720 == 811664013313310720 && Open:true
Entonces no crearia otro ticket y tendria que esperar para que se cierre

Como puedo obtener unicamente la **String**  del  **MembersID: [String]**
Ahora en Mongo DB me sale lo siguiente
Como podria unicamente escojer el **811664013313310720** del *MembersID["811664013313310720"]*

Comment: El segundo bloque de código qué es? Es un console log? de donde sale eso? Porque no parece tener un formato válido.

Comment: ```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("63d8080ffbe4f5403967c0ae"),
  TicketID: '2',
  ChannelID: '1069680997962092684',
  Closed: false,
  Locked: false,
  Type: 'Hola',
  Claimed: false,
  Open: false,
  __v: 0
}
```
Ese es del console log lo de arriba es los datos del mongoDB

Comment: Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y agrega cómo usas el modelo y haces la llamada y recibes los datos

Comment: Listo, mi pregunta fue editada espero que lo comprendan mejor

Comment: Gracias por la edición. Sin embargo sigo sin entender el problema. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] y [example]. Quizás te sirva como guía. gracias!

Comment: Osea lo unico que necesito saber es como obtener el STRING del MembersID: [String]

Comment: Como te decía en el primer comentario, el segundo bloque de código en tu respuesta no parece ser un JSON válido ni un objeto javascript válido. En el caso de que `"MembersID["811664013313310720"],` sea en realidad `"MembersID":["811664013313310720"],` (Es decir una key `"MembersID"` y un value `["811664013313310720"]` entonces para obtener el string numérico deberías hacer lo siguiente: `let elObjetoDeMongo = {"MembersID":["811664013313310720"]}; let membersID = elObjetoDeMongo.MembersID[0]`

Comment: Si, exactamente pero en caso que sea otro id como compruebo eso?

Comment: En pocas palabras como obtener solamente lo que tiene dentro del Array del MembersID

Comment: Justamente como te comente arriba `let membersID = elObjetoDeMongo.MembersID[0]` Por favor edita tu pregunta y corrige el formato

Comment: Entonces esa línea de código siempre me va a regresar el valor en el que esté?

Comment: Si, me parece rara tu pregunta de todos modos. Es un concepto bastante básico. Te recomiendo que leas sobre arreglos en javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array